# Connecting MySQL database to website with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

As the title indicates I'm trying to link my MySQL database to my website using php.

I'm using GoDaddy hosting for the MySQL database and I got this code directly from them and it's still not working for some reason, giving the error below.

Here's my code :

```
<?php
    $hostname = "trdlibrary.db.6253425.hostedresource.com";
    $username = "*******";
    $password = "*******";
    $dbname   = "trdlibrary";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later or contact an administrator for help.");
?>
```

Here's the error :

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\searchengine\dbconnect.php on
>   line 6 Unable to connect to database! Please try again later or
>   contact an administrator for help.

Can anyone see the issue?.. or is this something I need to contact GoDaddy's support line about.

**-- EDIT --**

I forgot to mention that I am running the web server off my local machine using XAMPP (so I can run the PHP scripts) but the MySQL server is off-site with GoDaddy, so 'localhost' won't work currently.

**-- EDIT #2 --**

So I learned that sadly, remote access of MySQL databases to GoDaddy requires a more expensive and 'higher tier' hosting package from them. So I just answered my own question, thanks to those who replied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup remote access to databases on Godaddy. You can refer to this [page](https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978) to see how to enable it.

Comment: I believe that feature has been removed? It's not in the user panel on the hosting area where the MySQL database items are.